# Most efficient way to get new messages

Tags: gmail-api

I have a process that looks for new messages in a users Gmail.  The message is added to an external database if it meets certain address criteria.

We have been using Users.History.List which returns all messages that have had a change made to them.  This is quite inefficient as we have to subsequently check each message to see if we have already processed it.

We are looking at alternatively using Users.Messages.List and checking the MsgId to see if it is larger than the previous check (we store the Id from that).  The assumption here is that the MsgId will keep getting larger.  Is this approach flawed?  What are others doing?

Many Thanks.

Comment: I'm facing the same situation, it works but as you say, it's inefficient. Did you figure out a better way to deal with this?

Comment: No - we just poll on a timed basis.  Is way more efficient.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example how to get only new message (using [Google's API Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/downloads#java)):

```java
List<History> histories = new ArrayList<History>();
ListHistoryResponse response = service.users().history()
                                      .list(userUID)
                                      .setStartHistoryId(startHistoryId)
                                      .execute();

//get all history events and not only the first page
while (response.getHistory() != null) {
    histories.addAll(response.getHistory());

    if (response.getNextPageToken() != null) {
        String pageToken = response.getNextPageToken();
        response = service.users().history().list(userUID)
                .setPageToken(pageToken)
                .setStartHistoryId(startHistoryId).execute();
    } else {
        break;
    }
}

//for each history element find the added messages
for (History history : histories) {
    List<HistoryMessageAdded> addedMessages = history.getMessagesAdded();
    
    if (addedMessages == null){
        continue;
    }

    //call to message.get for each HistoryMessageAdded
    for (HistoryMessageAdded addedMsg : addedMessages) {
        Message message = addedMsg.getMessage();
        Message rawMessage = service.users().messages()
                                    .get(userUID, message.getId())
                                    .setFormat("raw").execute();

    }
}
```

Probably there is a similar implementation in other languages/REST API.

You can use other history events such as: `messagesDeleted`, `labelsAdded` and `labelsRemoved`.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/history/list

Answer (score 3):

Message ID is unique and its value is never changed. To get new messages, you can use [history.list()](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/history/list), and give `historyId` of whatever the largest `historyId` you've previously for the message.

Here is the example response:

```
{
 "history": [
  {
   "id": "1825077",
   "messages": [
    {
     "id": "14b4c0dbc6ba9a57",
     "threadId": "14b4b4ae8cfbea5c"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "id": "1825087",
   "messages": [
    {
     "id": "14b4c0dc3ab5e49b",
     "threadId": "14b4b4ae8cfbea5c"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "id": "1825097",
   "messages": [
    {
     "id": "14b4c0e07e0f6545",
     "threadId": "14b4b4ae8cfbea5c"
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

1825097 is the largest `historyId` for the message "14b4c0e07e0f6545". Also `Msgid` didn't change here only history id is changed.

If you give 1825097 as history id and there is no change in the message, then the response will be 200 with headers. If you get response 404 error, you'll need to use [messages.list()](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) instead to perform a full sync.

Comment: We have been using the History Id but this returns all changes to threads/messages.  We only want new messages and want to avoid checking all the history against the messages we have already synchronised.  We only want a list of new messages if possible.

Comment: You can use messages.list(), give the label name and q value as "is:unread" to get all the unread messages.

Comment: Yes we are messages.list() and get all messages where the id is larger than the last synchronised messageId.  This seems to be the best way.  Unread would ignore any sent messages/opened messages I would have thought?

Comment: @PNC is there any official documentation which suggest that messageIds are always in increasing order . ?

Comment: @vinitpayal - no official documentation but we have been using this approach for several years now without issue.

Comment: Great also @PNC how are you guys passing largest message id which you have already synced to `messages.list` api  as looking into https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list there is no parameter for it.